# Jquery Autocomplete using codeigniter not showing on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

***Javascript Code***

```
$( "#cusname" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: base_url+'admin/auto_cusname',
            data: { term: $("#cusname").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
           var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                return obj.tag;
           }); 

           response(resp);
        }
    });
},
    minLength: 1
});
```

***Controller***

```
 public function auto_cusname(){
    $term = $this->input->get('term');
    if (isset($term)){
    $result = $this->mod_admin->autocusname($term);
    }else{
        $data['error'] = $term;
            $this->load->view('error', $data);
    }
    print json_encode($result);
}
```

***Model***

```
public function autocusname($search_term) {
$this->db->select('Firstname');
$this->db->like('Firstname', $search_term);
$response = $this->db->get($this->tbl_costumer,$this->uri->segment(2))->result_array();
// var_dump($response);die;

return $response;
}
```

***View***

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="cusname" name="cusname" placeholder="Customer Name"/>
</div>
```

My problems is when i try to query it on the browser i got this
     localhost/PPDOIMS/admin/auto_cusname?term=s

it outputs the data

```
 [{"Firstname":"Crisa"},{"Firstname":"Thomas "}]
```

but when try to view it on my page and type something i got no response.

is there something wrong on my code?